# can't find nuget packages from nuget server

Tags: visual-studio-2019, manage-nuget-packages

I know this question will be very ambiguous but that's how much I am blinded at this point.

When I use nuget package manager in my visual studio 2019, I can't find any package suppose to be returned from default nuget org such as Autofac or NeverNull.

no error messages, just simply "No packages found"

Anybody knows how to do any trial or any attempt to make, please shine me some light here.
I know that Package source: drop down list is set to "All" and I am at Browse tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I don't know how it got deleted,  (and actually I didn't know until now that it has to be explicitly listed in the available package sources)  however below link was missing in my settings, package sources for nuget.org

```
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```